# Angular unit test mocking a service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking

I want to unit test functions of a component.
Therefore I need a to mock a service (in accordance with the [angular testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-a-dependency)).

here my TestBed:

```
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [LanguageSelectorComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: LanguageSelectorService, useValue: userServiceStub }]
        });
```

here my userServiceStub:

```
            let userServiceStub: Partial<LanguageSelectorService>;
        userServiceStub = {
            _languages:
                [
                    {
                        ID: '',
                        Name: '',
                        ImageSrc: ''
                    },
                    {
                        ID: '',
                        Name: '',
                        ImageSrc: ''
                    }
                ]
        };
```

But at first "_language" is a private property, so it would not be found here.
At second, when I change it to public, I still get a error message on userServiceStub:

> [ts]
>   Type '{ _languages: { ID: string; Name: string; ImageSrc: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.
>     Types of property '_languages' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ ID: string; Name: string; ImageSrc: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>         Property '_isScalar' is missing in type '{ ID: string; Name: string; ImageSrc: string; }[]'.
>   let userServiceStub: Partial

**So what is the right way to mock the service values?**

Frank

Comment: You are getting a typescript error. Which is the reason to have userServiceStub of type Partial<LanguageSelectorService>; and not of simply type LanguageSelectorService?

Comment: @LlorençPujolFerriol
I don't understand you question. I use Partial because I find it at the testing guide. Without the partial I get the same error.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I didn't know actually that Partial was a type of es6, it hasn't to affect. Can you share some code of your LanguageSelectorService?

Comment: @Injectable()
export class LanguageSelectorService {
    private _projectsUrl = 'languages.json';
    private _configurationtemplatesUrl = 'configurationtemplates.json';
    private _configurationtemplatePDFUrl = 'configurationtemplatePDF.json';
    private _baseUrl: string;
    private _languages: Observable<ILanguage[]>;

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _logger: NGXLogger) {
        this._baseUrl = '../../api';
        this._languages = this._http
            .get<ILanguage[]>(`${this._baseUrl}/${this._projectsUrl}`);
    }

Comment: getLanguages(): Observable<ILanguage[]> {
        return this._languages;
    }
}

Comment: If you want help, please provide the code of your service. If you want to mocj something, you actually need that something in order to create the mock.

Comment: @trichetriche I provided the code allready above.

Comment: Don't put it in a comment ... Update your post.

Answer (score 0):

The service code:

```html
    @Injectable()
export class LanguageSelectorService {
    _projectsUrl = 'languages.json';
    _configurationtemplatesUrl = 'configurationtemplates.json';
    _configurationtemplatePDFUrl = 'configurationtemplatePDF.json';
    _baseUrl: string;
    public _languages: Observable<ILanguage[]>;

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _logger: NGXLogger) {
        this._baseUrl = '../../api';
        this._languages = this._http
            .get<ILanguage[]>(`${this._baseUrl}/${this._projectsUrl}`);
    }

    getLanguages(): Observable<ILanguage[]> {
        return this._languages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not mocking well the _languages property since it is an **Observable**, not an array. You should do like this:

```
let userServiceStub: Partial<LanguageSelectorService>;
    userServiceStub = {
        _languages: Observable.of( // or simply of() if you are using new rxjs piepeable version
            [
                {
                    ID: '',
                    Name: '',
                    ImageSrc: ''
                },
                {
                    ID: '',
                    Name: '',
                    ImageSrc: ''
                }
            ]
        )
    };
```

This should work and not give you any error. Of course, you will have to **.sbuscribe()** to it in order to get the array value, but it is synchronous, so you don't have to worry much about that.

Hope this helps.